# Get rendered element dimensions and properties without ref (element is a react functional component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-dom, react-ref

I am stuck at figuring out how can I get DOM rendered element information (`offsetHeight` for example) when the element rendered using a functional react component.

I know I can't use `ref`s on functional components and I can't rewrite the component into a class component because this component is given as an unknown children (which can be either a functional component or a class component).

Right now in my main component I iterate over the children and clone them with a `ref` property, however, when the child is a functional component, this obviously won't help me. What can I do to overcome this?

```
{React.Children.map(props.children, (c, i) => {
          newProps.ref = (ref) => { refList[i] = ref };
          return React.cloneElement(c, newProps);
        })
}
```

Comment: _"I know I can't use refs on functional components"_ - `useRef`?

Comment: @kinduser as far as I know (and it really didn't work for me), the children cannot be given a `ref` property if it is a functional component. It can not be referred because it doesn't return an instance.

Comment: The function component children can take a ref if you set the up with the forwardRef function.  Eventually you need to forward the ref to a DOM element.